# Calculate sum in mysqli database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a small database with products and prices. I want to calculate the sum of the column "orderpris", in my table called orders. And print this to the screen. Not sure if I'm anywhere near the solution but I thought this would work but it dont. What have I done wrong?

```
<?php       
function sum() { 
    /* Connect to database */
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin2', 'password', 'myshop');
    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Fel vid anslutning [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }


$results = mysqli_query("SELECT sum(orderpris) FROM orders") or die(mysqli_error());
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

}

    ?>

    <div>
       Total:&nbsp;<?php echo $rows['sum(orderpris)']; ?>
    </div>

<?php }
?>

<?php 
sum();
?>
```

Comment: change `sum(orderpris)` to `sum(orderpris) as sum` then you can use `$row['sum']`

Comment: you shouldn't use a core function as a custom function and then used as a core MySQL aggregate function; it could have adverse effects.

Comment: I should have said ` AS total` MySql will probably complain because sum is a key work .... bla bla   :-(

Comment: I used 'as total' and this worked! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

function sum() {
  /* Connect to database */    
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin2', 'password', 'myshop');
  if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Fel vid anslutning [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
  }
  $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT sum(orderpris) as total FROM orders") or die(mysqli_error());
  while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
      $iResult = 'Total:'.$rows['total'];
  }
  return $iResult;
}
echo sum();
```

1- I have changed:

```
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT sum(orderpris) as total FROM orders") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Instead:

```
$results = mysqli_query("SELECT sum(orderpris) FROM orders") or die(mysqli_error());
```

As you can see, mysqli_query function needs at least two parameters:

```
  -A link identifier, in your case it is $db
  -The query string.
```

2- I have added an alias 'total' to the query

-It works, but try to don't use database connection into your function, suppose that you have several functions and you need to connect to database , you will be repeating the same action every time.

-Try to move sum() function to a class

-Try to create a unique way to database connection and not several connections for each function.

Comment: This solution worked! I then moved the database connection and the function to a class instead like you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: If the solution works for you, try to mark it  as useful answer and maybe it will help to someone in the future.

Comment: I did that, but it says: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"